# How do extension wallets save sensitive user information?

Tags: wallet

Is there any standard practice about how all extension wallets (Phantom, Glow, Backpack, etc) store sensitive information like seed phrase or master private key?
As an extension dev, were should I save such information and how should I ensure the safety of the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to store this information only locally, encrypted by the password used to unlock the wallet. On Chrome, extensions store data in `C:\Users\[login_name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions` on Windows, or `/home/USER_NAME/.config/[chrome, chromium, brave, vivaldi, etc]/Default/Extensions` on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but two places to look might be:

- [Backpack GH Repo](https://github.com/coral-xyz/backpack)
- [Sollet Wallet GH Repo](https://github.com/project-serum/spl-token-wallet)